# AngularJS: fading out an element

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am using ng-animate, I had set it up as a dependency injection. Well, this is not working.

HTML

```
<p ng-show="atSomeCondition" class="notice">
    Some message.
</p>
```

CSS

```
.notice {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 2s;
    transition: all linear 2s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.notice.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of angular/angular-animate are you using?  I just tried your code in a plunker and it seems to be working fine:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aMLPgXUMmx5ZNtJfI91W?p=preview

This plunker uses version 1.4.3.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My Angular version is  1.3.15, animate version 1.4.3. During install it gave me a warning "Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one."

Comment: That's your problem.  I changed the plunker to use Angular 1.3.15 and animate 1.4.3, and the animate doesn't work.  You can use animate 1.3.15, or move both to 1.4.3.  Either option works.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked!  An upvote and checkmark will tell others that this is solved. :)